# Will there always be excess profit in the Cournot model equilibrium/monopoly

Tags: microeconomics, markets, monopoly, oligopoly, monopolistic-competition

So I'm studying market structures for the end of term, and I'm a bit confused about excess profits.

From what I can see, excess profits occur when the demand curve intersects the AC curve - the MR=MC quantity leads to a price which is above AC, and thus the firm earns excess/economic profits (as in monopoly). If the demand curve were tangent to the AC curve (as in long-run monopolistic competition), there are no excess profits, because the firm produces at AC.

My question is: is there any reason why the demand curve faced by a monopolist isn't just tangent to the AC curve? Or is it that this is the only situation where the monopolist doesn't earn economic profits? See the diagrams below.

[image: Only normal profits in long-run monopolistic competition] [image: Excess profits in monopoly]

Finally, what does this mean for a firm in a Cournot duopoly equilibrium, with no collusion? Does the competition from its rival leave it with a similar result as the firm in monopolistic competition with the demand curve tangent to the AC curve, or does it enjoy excess profits?

Comment: Hi Evan! Can you please define more precisely what you mean by "*excess profits*"? Positive profits?

Comment: "*is there any reason why the demand curve faced by a monopolist isn't just tangent to the AC curve?*" ... is there any reason why it should **generally** be tangential to the AC curve?

Comment: @Giskard Thanks, I mean supernoral or economic profits - as in, any profit earned by the firm above the minimum level of profit it would require to stay in business. Also, I don't see any reason why the demand curve should generally be tangential to the AC curve - my question is essentially whether this means it's possible to have a monopolist who doesn't earn excess profits

Comment: Is this different from positive economic profit?

Comment: No, that's not different - I mean positive economic profit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the AC curve is assumed convex and demand is assumed linear, as in the figure, then an AC curve tangent to the demand line means that AC > P at all quantities but one (where AC = P). Thus the monopolist makes zero profits in his optimum. However, for cost and demand parameters drawn from a continuous distribution this is a probability-zero event. You'd rather expect that either AC > P everywhere (and the monopolist would have left the market) or AC < P somewhere (the standard example). Analogous considerations hold for a Cournot duopoly.

Comment: Yes, when the number of firms is an integer, $AC=P$ is unlikely to hold, and the long-run equilibrium is characterized by $AC(y_N)<p_N$ for all active firms (of the economy with $N$ firms), and $AC(y_{N+1})>p_{N+1}$ if $N+1$ firms were active,

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm just a bit confused by what you mean by "cost and demand parameters drawn from a continuous distribution".

Comment: @Evan, I just meant that for "randomly chosen" parameter values this case will "never" happen, sort of.